# ¿Cómo crear inserciones simultáneas con MySQL para que los datos no se mezclen?

Tags: sql, insert

Escribir un "insert multiple" como:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo1, campo2) 
VALUES ('v1c1', 'v1c2'), ('v2c1', 'v2c2'),('v3c1', 'v3c2');
```

Garantiza que no se escribirían en la DB inserciones simultáneas en caso de que muchos usuarios ejecuten esa sentencia al mismo tiempo, ¿es correcto? Es decir, se garantiza que se escribirá la base de datos de 3 en 3 :

```
('v1c1', 'v1c2'), ('v2c1', 'v2c2'),('v3c1', 'v3c2');
```

y en ningún momento sería posible que esto:

User "X" ejecuta la insercción:

```
('v1c1x', 'v1c2x'), ('v2c1x', 'v2c2x'),('v3c1x', 'v3c2x');
```

User "Y" ejecuta la insercción al mismo tiempo que User "X"

```
('v1c1y', 'v1c2y'), ('v2c1y', 'v2c2y'),('v3c1y', 'v3c2y');
```

termine por ejemplo asi(NÓTESE LAS LETRAS QUE REPRESENTAN A CADA USUARIO):

```
('v1c1Y', 'v1c2Y'), ('v1c1X', 'v1c2X'),('v2c1Y', 'v2c2Y');
```

Al momento de escribirse en la base de datos.

Ya no es necesario usar cosas como "LOCK TABLE", ¿es correcto?

Comment: No termino de entender cuál es el problema en sí. Lee sobre Transacciones, quizá te aclare algunos conceptos.

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto al problema descrito:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo1, campo2) VALUES ('v1c1', 'v1c2');
```

Deberia funcionar igual de bien que

```
INSERT INTO tabla (campo1, campo2) VALUES ('v1c1', 'v1c2'), ('v2c1', 'v2c2'),('v3c1', 'v3c2');
```

Sin dar el problema que describes.

Sin embargo, yo tenia errores de exactamente este tipo por no implementar CSRF_token. Un token implementado para protección contra ataques CSRF. Como efecto secundario protege a usuarios de otros usuarios, es decir, asegura que valores de formulario pasados por un usuario serán ejecutados separadamente de otros usuarios.

Comment: ok , gracias a los que respondieron  =)

Comment: @codethat puedes marcar respuesta como aceptada, o poner tu propia respuesta que te ha ayudado resolver el problema